# Parsing non-standard XML in GO

Tags: xml, go

I have a 4.5 million line XML file, and I cannot figure out a way to parse the information out using the decoder.DecodeElement() function.

A snippet of the XML:

```
<dt
    xmlns:directive="d"
    xmlns:ref="ref">
    <Data>
        <directive:Entry Name='abcd'>
            <list>
                <map>
                    <directive:Entry Name='id'>
                        <Integer>21</Integer>
                    </directive:Entry>
                    <directive:Entry Name='t'>
                        <Date>T14:31:43.823Z</Date>
                    </directive:Entry>
                </map>
            </list>
        </directive:Entry>
    </Data>
</dt>
```

So the above constitutes one line of the XML file. My goal is to extract 't' and 'id'.

My current attempt involves creating a struct:

```
type DT struct {
    id string `xml:"Data"` // This is my attempt to get the entire Data portion/segment/chunk(?)
}
```

The code to perform the actual decoding:

```
decoder := xml.NewDecoder(readInFile())

for {
    t, _ := decoder.Token()
    if t == nil {
        break
    }

    switch se := t.(type) {
    case xml.StartElement:
        inE := se.Name.Local

        if inE == "dt" {
            var dt DT
            decoder.DecodeElement(&dt, &se)

            fmt.Println(&dt)
        }
    }
}
```

The above code, when run, outputs

```
&{}
```

Which tells me that no information can be parsed out. The same is true when if I output

```
fmt.Println(&dt.id)
```

Could someone please help me. I am not sure if the reason my output is blank is due to the way I am extracting in the struct, or an issue with my decoding.

Comment: The XML is well-formed, so it's pretty standard.

Comment: Really? I've never seen the directive:entry before, and I believe that is what is throwing this off.

Comment: That's called a namespace and getting an empty result can be a result of not defining this namespace.

Comment: But I don't know about how Go handles namespaces, so I cannot help you in this regard.

Comment: Okay well now I know I need to look into parsing namespaces, so thank you for that!

Comment: You have to export the `id` field, otherwise the XML package can't assign values to it.

Comment: @Peter I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by exporting the field? How would I do this?

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/basics/3

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using decoder.DecodeElement() I would recommend you use xml.Unmarshal, and for `xml.Unmarshal` to be able to do what you want it to do, the `DT` type's structure has to match the `<dt>` element's structure following the rules documented [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal).

For example something like this:

```
type DT struct {
    DataEntry struct {
        List []EntryMap `xml:"list"`
    } `xml:"Data>Entry"`
}

type EntryMap struct {
    Entries []Entry `xml:"map>Entry"`
}

type Entry struct {
    Name  string `xml:",attr"`
    Value string `xml:",any"`
}
```

You can then loop over `dt.DataEntry.List[N].Entries` to get what you need.

https://play.golang.org/p/3XxmYQ4ECza

Comment: Okay I'll give this a go at implementing, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Im using [xmlquery](https://github.com/antchfx/xmlquery) library to parse and extract data from XML document.

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"strings"

"github.com/antchfx/xmlquery"
)

func main() {
var s = `<dt
xmlns:directive="d"
xmlns:ref="ref">
<Data>
<directive:Entry Name='abcd'>
<list>
    <map>
            <directive:Entry Name='id'>
                    <Integer>21</Integer>
            </directive:Entry>
            <directive:Entry Name='t'>
                    <Date>T14:31:43.823Z</Date>
            </directive:Entry>
        </map>
    </list>
    </directive:Entry>
</Data>
</dt>`

doc, err := xmlquery.Parse(strings.NewReader(s))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
id := xmlquery.FindOne(doc, "//directive:Entry[@Name='id']/Integer")
fmt.Println(id.InnerText())
t := xmlquery.FindOne(doc, "//directive:Entry[@Name='t']/Date")
fmt.Println(t.InnerText())
}
```

It's very simple and easy used.